# Find why Xamarin app Crashes randomly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am making a app with `Xamarin.Forms`, the app in the iOS doesn't crash but in Android, Application is crashing randomly, even if I only switch the tabs.
What is the best way to find what is making the app to stop working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to find what is making the app to stop working?

well to add exception handling

```
try {
    // ... 
} catch(Exception e) { 
    // ...
}
```

or like the below example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try{
        ExceptionHandler(1);
        ExceptionHandler(2);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        System.out.println(" error to be checked");         
    }
    testException(0);
}


public static void ExceptionHandler(int i) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    if(i =1 ){
        FileNotFoundException myException = new FileNotFoundException("error for code 1 "+i);
        throw myException;
    }else if(i =2){
        throw new IOException("error on 2 ");
    }

}
```

Comment: The example is to put in every page ?

Comment: @Phill start with the first exception. the second class is to create your own exception and error

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into a crash reporting service like Hockey App (https://hockeyapp.net/ -- the free level is enough for getting crash reports). You'll get crashes reported there, including crashes in code that you can't catch.

Crash reports aren't quite as handy has being able to break in the debugger, but it's often enough to point you in the right direction.

Instructions on integrating Hockey App to a Xamarin.Forms app: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-cross-platform/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-xamarin